# Move VM To New Subscription

Tags: azure

I have a new subscription to Azure but have existing VM's in a prior subscription.  What is the easiest/best way to move my VM's to the new Subscription?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there's another option, but you can do this with powershell:

```
 # Copy a virtual machine to a different subscription (no VNET)
  .\vmcopy.ps1 -SourceSubscription "source subscription" ` 
             -DestinationSubscription "destination subscription" ` 
             -VirtualMachineName "existingvmname" ` 
             -SourceServiceName "sourcecloudservice" ` 
             -DestinationServiceName "destinationcloudservice" ` 
             -DestinationStorageAccount "destinationstorageaccount" ` 
             -Location "West US" 


  # Copy a virtual machine to a different subscription and specify an existing virtual network and subnet. 
  .\vmcopy.ps1 -SourceSubscription "source subscription" ` 
               -DestinationSubscription "destination subscription" ` 
               -VirtualMachineName "existingvmname" ` 
               -SourceServiceName "sourcecloudservice" ` 
               -DestinationServiceName "destinationcloudservice" ` 
               -DestinationStorageAccount "destinationstorageaccount" ` 
               -VNETName "DestinationVNET" ` 
               -SubnetName "DestinationSubnet"
```

Source / more info

http://michaelwasham.com/2014/01/21/copy-a-windows-azure-virtual-machine-between-subscriptions/

Answer (score 0):

For those who wonder if there is a better option: Yes, there is.
When you want to `move` instead of `copy` (as Thiago suggested) you should do the following:
Create a JSON file with this content:

```
{
  "targetResourceGroup": "/subscriptions/<TARGET-SUBSCRIPTION-ID>/resourceGroups/<TARGET-RESOURCEGROUP-NAME>",
  "resources": [
    "<SOURCE-RESOURCE-ID>"
  ]
}
```

Note that you may have multiple resources which belongs to a VM: VM, cloudservice, storage account, VNet, reserved IP, ...
You need to add the resource IDs of all these resources into the JSON above.

Then you can run:

```
armclient post https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<SOURCE-SUBSCRIPTION-ID>/resourceGroups/<SOURCE-RESOURCEGROUP>/moveResources?api-version=2015-01-01 @<PAHT_TO_JSON> -verbose
```

on your command line. You will ned `armclient`, which you can install by using `choco`:

```
choco install armclient
```